# How I can implement Mouse Release event on QTableWidget in PyQt5 after clicking then selecting multiple rows by dragging mouse?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have a table with task IDs and some more columns. My task is to return all the IDs of selected rows after mouse click and drag has been finished with mouse release. In the original documentation's QTableWidget's SIGNALS section I found only "Clicked" signal, which works but only for one row - when I'm clicking on one row, it's works after mouse release, but when I'm click and drag (to select multiple rows) it's not emitting signal after mouse release.
I'm in Python3, please describe there if possible.
Thank you very much !

Comment: Override the `mouseReleaseEvent` of the QTableWidget, or install an event filter on it, then call `selectedItems()`. If you want more help, please [edit] your question and provide a proper [mre].

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll come back with the example if the issue remains unsolved.